# correctGuess() and incorrectGuess() functions for a quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, quiz

In my JavaScript quiz, I have two functions below which are not DRY. What i want to do is to cut it, so everything below `var = text` would be used only once not twice.

My concept is to enclose these two functions in bigger function (e.g. `guess()`) and keep the trimmed `correctGuess()` and `incorrectGuess()` within it.

Now here's the question: how can I call such nested function as described above from outside scope. I was thinking about something like: `guess().correctGuess()` which is obviously wrong but I wanted to share a concept.

Additionally, when e.g. `correctGuess()` would be called, is rest of the commands within our main `guess()` function would be executed?

[Fiddle with full code](https://jsfiddle.net/janjanjan/35jxn2j4/26/)

```
function correctGuess(i) {

    totalScore++;
    questionNumber++;

    var text = "Correct!";

    var updatePage = ['<div id="answerDiv">' +
        '<h1>' + text + '<h1>' +
        '<h2>Total Score: ' + totalScore + '</h2></div>'
    ];

    mainContent[html](updatePage);

    $('#answerDiv')[fadeIn]("slow");
    $('#answerDiv').append('<button id="nextButton">Next Question</button>');

    $('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
        if (questionNumber == allQuestions.length && totalScore <= 4) {
            results()
        } else {
            question(questionNumber)
        }
    })
};

function incorrectGuess(i) {
    totalScore--;
    questionNumber++;

    var text = "Wrong!";

    var updatePage = ['<div id="answerDiv">' +
        '<h1>' + text + '<h1>' +
        '<h2>Total Score: ' + totalScore + '</h2></div>'
    ];

    mainContent[html](updatePage);

    $('#answerDiv')[fadeIn]("slow");
    $('#answerDiv').append('<button id="nextButton">Next Question</button>');

    $('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
        if (questionNumber == allQuestions.length && totalScore <= 4) {
            results();
        } else {
            question(questionNumber);
        }

    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

i did not test or execute this code

just put it in an object?

```
var Guess = {

    score : 0,
    questions_count : 0,

    text : null,

    correct : function () {
        this.score+= 1;
        this.questions_count += 1;
        this.text = 'Correct!';
    },

    incorrect : function () {
        this.score-=1;
        this.questions_count += 1;
        this.text = 'Wrong!';
    },

    update : function () {
        var updatePage = ['<div id="answerDiv">' +
        '<h1>' + text + '<h1>' +
        '<h2>Total Score: ' + this.score + '</h2></div>'
        ];

        mainContent[html](updatePage);

        $('#answerDiv')[fadeIn]("slow");
        $('#answerDiv').append('<button id="nextButton">Next Question</button>');

        $('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
            if (this.questions_count == allQuestions.length && totalScore <= 4) {
                results();
            } else {
                question(this.questions_count);
            }

        });
    }
};
```

#### chaining

key to chaining calls is to return the right thing. Simple example:

```
function test() {
    var x = {
        correct : function () {
            console.log('correct');
        },
        incorrect : function() {
            console.log('incorrect');
        }
    };

return x;
}

test().correct();
```

Comment: Hey,that's basically 3 functions within Object Literal,I was thinking about doing the same.

But do you know maybe a way to make a big function guess() and within it enclose correctGuess() and incorrectGuess() so we would avoid making 4 objects?

Comment: @Johnny updated my answer